# Why use getters and setters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I know how getter and setter work in JavaScript. What I don't understand is why we need them when we can get the same result using normal functions? Consider the following code:

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'Jimmy',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}

console.log(person.fullName);    // Jimmy Smith
```

We can easily replace getter with a function:

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'Jimmy',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    fullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}

console.log(person.fullName());    // Jimmy Smith
```

I don't see the point of writing getter and setter.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28222366/2545680) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: This is not an opinion based question. It is completely valid and relates to accessibility of private variables. I was about to provide a completely valid answer.

Comment: Well, for those interested, getters and setters are a method of allowing accessibility of private variables inside a function. This ensures a user cannot get or set the variable unless they use the defined getter/setter methods.

Comment: @Inkdot The question is why to use `.foo` instead of `.getFoo()`/`.setFoo()`; they both achieve the same thing WRT encapsulation.

Answer (score 53):

A difference between using a getter or setter and using a standard function is that getters/setters are automatically invoked on assignment. So it looks just like a normal property but behind the scenes you can have extra logic (or checks) to be run just before or after the assignment.

So if you decide to add this kind of extra logic to one of the existing object properties that is already being referenced, you can convert it to getter/setter style without altering the rest of the code that has access to that property.

**Edit:** Here is an example for an extra logic, this class counts how many times its name is read:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.refCount = 0;
    this._name = 'the class';
  }

  get name() {
    this.refCount++;
    console.log(`name is read ${this.refCount} times.`);
    return this._name;
  }
}

const myClass = new MyClass();

let maxMessages = 5;
const t = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(`name: ${myClass.name}`);
  
  if (--maxMessages < 1) {
    console.log('done');
    clearInterval(t);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: And the question is why `foo.bar = baz` using a setter is any better than `foo.setBar(baz)`…

Comment: The question was slightly different than what you understand anyway, added a second paragraph to clarify the benefit.

Comment: Assuming you're designing an interface from the beginning to use getters/setters instead of retrofitting it… what's your answer then?

Comment: That's what the second paragraph explains.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm saying I'm writing a new object today which does not have any references yet, and I'm opting to write `get foo()`/`set foo()` instead of `getFoo()`/`setFoo()`… why would I?

Comment: You cannot use the assignments like  myObj.foo = 'some data' with getFoo, setFoo. You always need to call those functions. And if you change your mind later, say to add extra logic, you need to convert all references to function calls.

Answer (score 5):

```
// A regular function can set and get (return) a value similar to a getter and setter function

function Car() {
    const fuel = 50
    return {
        fuel
    }
}

const car = Car()
console.log(car.fuel) 
>>> 50
car.fuel = 100
console.log(car.fuel)
>>> 100

// A getter function can encapuslate a property and therefore create safe code that cannot be changed. 

function Car1() {
    const fuel = 50
    return {
        get fuel() { return fuel }
    }
}

const car1 = Car1()
car1.fuel = 3000
console.log(car1.fuel)
>>> 50

// A setter function can further safeguard a property by imposing conditions on it that need to be met.

function Car2() {
    let fuel = 50
    return {
        get fuel() { return fuel },
        set fuel(value) {
            fuel = value
            if (value > 100) fuel = 100
        }
    }
}

const car2 = Car2()
car2.fuel = 3000
console.log(car2.fuel) 
>>> 100
```

Comment: Why is `fuel` able to get overwritten in the first place? I thought `const` can't be overwritten

Comment: @NHerwich he isn't overwriting the inner const (which is not a prop and can't be accessed). He is creating a new prop called fuel and setting it's value.