# Why do I need use getter If I can do the same thing using function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter

Here I am using getter to get the value of language property.

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "en",
  get lang() {
    return this.language;
  };
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.lang;
```

The question is why do I need to use the getter if I can get the same result using this piece of code?

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  language : "en",
  lang : function() {
    return this.language;
  };
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.lang();
```

Comment: You **don't need** to use a getter. I'm not sure why you have this idea. It's ultimately your choice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342623/why-use-getters-and-setters-in-javascript

Comment: At any rate, reasoning for getters is exactly the same as here [Why use getters and setters/accessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1568091) (although in Java, they are still methods you execute).