# While searching for getters and setters, I found a JavaScript code that I didn't understand

Tags: javascript

```js
function Car() {
  const fuel = 50
  return {
    fuel
  }
}

const car = Car();
console.log(car);
```

I happened to see the code above, and I thought the value of car would be 50, but strangely, car became an object. Can you tell me why car is an object? I happened to see it in the link below.
[Why use getters and setters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342623/why-use-getters-and-setters-in-javascript)

Comment: `return fuel` will give you 50 and `return { fuel }` will give you `{ fuel: 50 }`. *why you're getting an object?* because you are returning an object.

Comment: console it like this and see the result
console.log(car.fuel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the curly braces `{}` when it returns. These mean that it is an object that contains `fuel`. If you returned just fuel(without `{}` ) then it would be 50 as you expected.